# Stop infinite loop in react native useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am calling one function through `setInterval` but function go to infinite loop and my applicaiton get stuck. It's happen it on android, Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      sendCoordinate(location);
    }, 180000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [location]);
```

**A function that I am calling**

```
const sendCoordinate = async (locParms) => {
    console.log("@2 it working3", checkDayStatus, location);
    if (checkDayStatus === "Started") {
      let data = {
        lat:
          locParms !== null
            ? locParms && locParms.lat
            : location && location.lat,
        lng:
          locParms !== null
            ? locParms && locParms.lng
            : location && location.lng,
        dispatcher_id: 1,
        truck_id: 1,
      };

      return await LocationAPI.sendLocationFeed(data);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please show the rest of that component

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for the comment, I've updated the question. Please take a look

Comment: It's not right to use the location object as a use effect dependency,
what kind of parameter do you need from that object? pathname? or something else?

so use it like  [location.pathname],

Comment: from your last update, you can use [location.lng, location.lat] as dependencies

Comment: Can you please answer to the question and add a small code snippet?

Comment: Also,a question why do you need setInterval here?

Comment: @NverAbgaryan I want to run this function after every 3 minutes to get store user location

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that your timer is created every time, just leave the useEffect arguments empty, [location] -> []

Comment: I tried with empty arguments but still function runs infinite

Comment: try ty make async function in useEffect body 
(async () => {
            
        })();

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    sendCoordinate(location);
  }, 180000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [location.lng, location.lat]);
```

So you need to change the location from the dependency array like this.

Comment: Not working it still go to infinite